# Index changes with varchar values

Tags: mysql, indexing

My query shows different for different varchar values. Structure of my table is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `equipmentdata` (
`EqpmDataDBId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SerialNumber` double DEFAULT '0',
`ReadValue` float DEFAULT '0',
`ReadTime` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`DataType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`EquipmentDBId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`EquipmentCustomId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`LocationCustomId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`ChannelCustomId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`ChannelName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`IsUploaded` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`EqpmDataDBId`),
UNIQUE KEY `SerialNumber`(`SerialNumber`,`EquipmentCustomId`,`LocationCustomId`,`ChannelCustomId`),
KEY `ReadTime` (`LocationCustomId`,`EquipmentCustomId`,`ChannelCustomId`,`ReadTime`),
KEY `SECONDARY` (`EqpmDataDBId`,`LocationCustomId`,`EquipmentCustomId`,`ChannelCustomId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

But this query takes different time for different data. Also i mean to use the Secondary index for the following query but it doesnt.

```
SELECT * FROM EquipmentData WHERE   EqpmDataDBId > 41500823 AND 
LocationCustomId = '192.168.3.6-8050' AND EquipmentCustomId = 'TP-3'
AND ChannelCustomId = 'Temp-0'  ORDER BY EqpmDataDBId ASC LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to take different time for different data?

Comment: @Neels may be its also not using the index

Answer (score 0):

You can force the SQL optimizer to use the Indexes available on your table by using the `USE INDEX` clause. Here is the documentation for the same: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Your query will transform to something like

```
SELECT * FROM EquipmentData 
USE INDEX(ReadTime,SECONDARY)
WHERE   EqpmDataDBId > 41500823 
AND LocationCustomId = '192.168.3.6-8050' 
AND EquipmentCustomId = 'TP-3'
AND ChannelCustomId = 'Temp-0'  
ORDER BY EqpmDataDBId ASC LIMIT 25
```

Hope this reduces your execution time.

Comment: I have 4 million data on this table. Any other way to speed up the query. It still taking about 5 to 10 seconds. Or is a normal time.

Comment: For 4 million data I guess 5 secs is a decent tradeoff. If you can not live with that then I guess you need to upgrade your architecture to high performance models like Hadoop and HDFS instead of normal RDBMS. :)